# How to Pass return value to other classes without executing the method multiple times

Tags: java, class, return-value

I have the class:

```
public class Provider { 
public static int getNumberofObjects() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input Number of Objects: ");

    int numberOfObjects = in.nextInt();

    return numberOfObjects;
}}
```

How can I pass the just numberOfObjects variable without having to prompt the user to input again a new number of objects each time that I want this variable?

What I am doing is:

```
public class B {
Provider provider = new Provider();

int numberOfObjects= Provider.getNumberofObjects(); }
```

but since I use the numberOfobjects in multiple methods in this class, every time I get prompted to enter new values.

Comment: Read the number of objects in a different class/method and store it there. Then, when create a new instance of `Provider`, set this number of objects.

Comment: You don't need an instance of a class to call a static method of a class. Notice, you're not even using the provider variable.

Comment: @GriffeyDog OP's not using any instance of `Provider` class to execute `Provider.getNumberofObjects();`

Comment: No, but he is creating one: `Provider provider = new Provider();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is to cache the result in the provider, and return it on all subsequent calls, like this:

```
public class Provider { 
    boolean gotNumber = false;
    int theNumber;
    public int getNumberofObjects() {
        if (!gotNumber) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Input Number of Objects: ");
            theNumber = in.nextInt();
            gotNumber = true;
        }
        return theNumber;
    }
}
```

This implementation requests the number from the user only the first time the `getNumberofObjects()` method is invoked; all subsequent invocations use `theNumber` read in the first invocation.

Note that I made `getNumberofObjects()` method non-static, so you need to pass `new Provider()` to the classes that need the number.

Comment: +1 Although I'd probably skip the boolean by just initializing theNumber to Integer.MIN_VALUE and then if-check for that value instead of the boolean.

Comment: @splungebob I know that the next time I do something like that, one of our QAs would enter -2147483648 to annoy me ;-)

Comment: LOL - then switch to a long, I say!

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable as instance variable (defined at class level) instead of using it inside the method